# Lock file while Imagick writeImage() executing

Tags: php, imagick

Is it possible to lock the file img.jpg until Imagick creates it?

```
$image->writeImage('img.jpg')
```

Comment: Can you say why you want to do this. I could try to imagine why, but answering your question would be easier if the use-case was clearer.

Comment: @Danack when user tries to get this file while it already exists but have not been completely created, user gets broken file

Comment: Have you seen this actually happen? ImageMagick should be using atomic file operations...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure the problem you are describing actually exists as a problem. No on else has ever reported it.

However, even if it is a problem, you don't want to use file locking here....that is for solving a separate set of problems.

Instead what you want to use is atomic operations, that are done 'instantaneously' by the computer.

```
$created = false;
for ($i=0; $i<5 && $created == false; $i++) {
    // Create a temp name
    $tmpName = "temp".rand(10000000, 99999999).".jpg";

    // Open it. The x+ means 'do not create if file already exists'.
    $fileHandle = @fopen($tmpName, 'x+');
    if ($fileHandle === false) {
        // The file with $tmpName already exists, or we otherwise failed
        // to create the file, loop again.
        continue;
    }
    // We don't actually want the file-handle, we just wanted to make sure 
    // we had a uniquely named file ending with .jpg so just close it again.
    // You could also use tempnam() if you don't care about the file extension.
    fclose($fileHandle);
    // Writes the image data to the temp file name.
    $image->writeImage($tmpName);
    rename($tmpName, 'img.jpg');
    $created = true;
}

if ($created === false) {
    throw new FailedToGenerateImageException("blah blah");
}
```

There's no locking in there....but it is not possible for any process to read the data from img.jpg while it is being written to. If there are any other processes that have img.jpg while the rename occurs, their file-handle to the old version of the file will continue to exist, and they will continue to read the old file, until they close and open it again.